# Need help to set z-index for Drop Down Menu

Tags: css

on my site brain.hostug.com I have added another CSS Menu, but the first one (on top) in creating a little problem. 
The first Menu at the top has a " About HostUG " li, which has a small drop down list.
After adding the second menu just below that first menu, whenever I hover the mouse on First Menu's " About HostUG " it display the drop down but these options display behind the second menu. 
I know about z-index in css but don't know how to use it exactly. 
Can any one please visit https://brain.hostug.com and check the top right menu.

Thank you!!
[This is the screenshot if you need to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9ifU.png)

This is the CSS of top navigation.

```
.siteHeader .navigation
{
    float: right;
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li
{
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li a
{
    display: block;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-transition: background 200ms, color 200ms;
    -moz-transition: background 200ms, color 200ms;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li a.dropdown
{
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li a span
{
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: none;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li:hover a
{
    padding: 9px 19px;
    color: #fed327;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #222;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #383838;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #383838;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #383838;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li:hover a.dropdown
{
    padding: 9px 19px 10px 19px;
    border-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li ul.dropdown
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 0;
    padding:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.siteHeader .navigation li ul.dropdown li
{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li ul.dropdown li a
{
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: none;
    background: #222;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li ul.dropdown li:first-child a
{
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li ul.dropdown li a:hover
{
    color: #fed327;
    background: #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px #191919;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px #191919;
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px #191919;
}

.siteHeader .navigation li:hover ul.dropdown
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: relative` from rule `#cssmenu ul`. I don't see any real meaning of it.

Answer (score 0):

add `position: relative;` to .siteHeader. It will be perfect.

That is

```
.siteHeader {
position: relative;
z-index: 4;
width: 100%;
height: 90px;
font: 13px "Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```